# Ionic 3 not finding assets when built for Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

When I serve my project there is no problem, but when I build it for android it fails.

It even fails to load its fonts: `E/AndroidProtocolHandler: Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/assets/fonts/roboto-bold.ttf` and gets stuck on splashscreen.

When I change asset path from `../assets` to `/../../assets` or `./assets` it loads, but fonts and background images are still not found.

I'm using the latest version and the default assets folder in `src`

Comment: These error with font occur in any ionic project. It did not effect to your project and you can ignore it. If you want to get assets image in `.html` file use url: `assets/...`. If in css file, use `../assets/...`

Comment: Problem is that, as I said, using `../assets/`  in css - freezes my app. I'm now in the process of reinstalling everything and trying to deploy blank test project with a background image

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solved

Now after reinstalling cordova etc I tried a blank project - It works.

1) In my scss I had:

`$assets: "../assets/";
$font-path: $assets+"fonts";`
Looks like android did not like that (but I added it later)

1. I removed android platform + cordova
2. deleted  `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`
3. ran `npm-check-updates` just in case ran `
4. ran `npm install`
5. added back cordova and android platform
6. deployed to android

There are some bugs, but images are now showing